# How to type unicode characters by name in spacemacs?

Tags: unicode, emacs, spacemacs

Is there some plugin that allows you to type unicode characters by name easily?

For example :

- Writing `\gamma` and hitting `TAB` would replace the `\gamma` with `γ`.
- Writing `\Gamma` and ... with `Γ`.
- Writing `\->` ... `→`.

Et cetera.

Answer (score 3):

`C-x 8 RET` lets you do this anywhere in Emacs.  I imagine it works for Spacemacs too, but someone will correct me if that is not quite correct.

It prompts you for the Unicode name with completion (ignoring case).

You can alternatively enter just the numeric code point for the character, instead of completing to its name.

---

*[Caveat: Dunno whether Spacemacs plays nicely with Icicles - haven't tried it.]*

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles), and if option `icicle-read-char-by-name-multi-completion-flag` is non-nil, then **`C-x 8 RET`** is enhanced in a few ways:

- It shows in `*Completions*`, for each candidate Unicode
  character, its name and code point, as well as *the character
  itself*.
- When you cycle among the matching candidates, the name and code
  point of the current candidate are shown in the *mode line*.  The
  code point is shown in hexadecimal, octal, and decimal
  notations.
- Completion candidates are in fact [*multi-completions*](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Completions), meaning
  that you can *match* against the name or the *code point*, or both.
- You can even *match the character* itself.  Why might you want to
  do that?  To see the corresponding Unicode character name(s),
  including any old names.  For example, for the character **`` ` ``**
  (grave accent) you get these two completion candidates:

  ```
  GRAVE ACCENT      60      `
  SPACING GRAVE     60      `
  ```

  The main purpose for this is to show you the characters and code
  points together with their names (WYSIWYG).  The characters are
  shown in `*Completions*` using the same font as the frame from
  which you invoked `C-x 8 RET`.  That you can also match against
  the characters themselves is just a nice-to-have.

The most important features of the Icicles version of `C-x 8 RET`
are (a) seeing the characters and code points (WYSIWYG) and (b)
being able to use [*progressive completion*](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion), so you can use multiple
simple patterns instead of a single complex pattern.

Comment: There is no Icicle layer available in spacemacs, but I think it should be possible to create my own. I will look into that.

Comment: @FordO.: Icicles is available from MELPA. [This](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Libraries#BulkIciclesDownload) describes how to obtain Icicles. Dunno about compatibility between Icicles and Spacemacs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use spacemacs, so I'm not sure if this works there.

I set `default-input-method` to `"TeX"`.  I can toggle to it with `toggle-input-method` (`C-\`).  When it's enabled, there's a `\` on the far left of the mode line.

This isn't the same as entering unicode chars by name, but probably closer to what you described.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "there's a ` \ ` on the far left of the mode line". How can I use it for unicode input? Is it a simpler solution then hitting `C-x 8 RET`?

Comment: The `\ ` in the mode line is just an indicator to tell you that the TeX input method is enabled.  Input methods make it "easy" to type certain characters.  Which characters are "easy" and what exactly "easy" means depends on the specific input method.  The TeX input method makes it easy to input unicode characters that are common in math, e.g. Greek letters and mathematical symbols, and it does it in a way that mimics TeX (e.g. `\gamma` inserts `γ`).  Your examples made it seem like that's what you were interested in, instead of say Chinese or smiley faces or other types of unicode characters.

Comment: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TeXInputMethod
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InputMethods

Comment: It works in spacemacs and the usage is as follows: type `\gamma` and the input will transform into `γ`; actually it will transform while you type into the current match of a LaTeX name and there is no need for TAB etc. You can type subscript and superscript letters by typing `_` or `^` before the letter. See also `C-h I`(describe-input-method).